# Test class for setters & getters in virtual class

Tags: apex, unit-test, code-coverage, getter, setter

How to write test class to cover setters and getters in virtual class. Please help to get code coverage for the below class

```
public virtual class TriggerHandlerExtension {
 
    public List<String> setTriggerRecursionContexts {
        get;
        set {triggerContextsForRecursion = value;}
    }
       
    
    // Allow users to allow recursion for certain contexts
    public virtual List<String> getTriggerContextsForRecursion() {
        return triggerContextsForRecursion;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Testing a virtual class it he same as testing a non-virtual class. Instantiate it and call the appropriate methods.

```
TriggerHandlerExtension extension = new TriggerHandlerExtension();
extension.setTriggerRecursionContexts = new String[] { 'Account' };
System.assert(new String[] { 'Account' } == extension.getTriggerContextsForRecursion());
```